# Can we carry engineering electronics stuffs to New Zealand?

Tags: air-travel

I am traveling to New Zealand in Feb 2018 for studies.I have some electronics  stuffs for my projects, blog and learning such as following:

1. Few Micro-controllers such as Arduino, BeagleBoard etc and USB based Logic Analyzer
2. Some passive elements like resistors, capacitors, diodes etc.
3. Few sensors
4. A couple of IC's and 9V batteries
5. A Multimeter
6. And a bunch of wires

All the above, I will pack it in one compact box. So can I carry these stuffs while I travel through Air?.

If not, would it be possible to send it via courier along with some other stuffs of mine before I travel?.

Any information on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I live in New Zealand and play with electronics as well).  It should not be an issue.  I've travelled from Auzzie to NZ with lots of bits and pieces from started IOT projects on a conference (including tools like soldering irons and multimeters).  No one cared or battered an eyelid.   I've also carried lots of electronics in and out of New Zealand for other projects - never had an issue.

I'd suggest putting the electronics in checked baggage, but any Lithium batteries need to be carry-on. (Lithium batteries in carry-on is some kind of aviation law requirement in most parts of the world).  Similarly, wire cutters and tools need to go in checked baggage or they risk confiscation.

From a point of view of bringing the stuff into NZ, you are fine as well, They only really care about things which could carry pests or disease - although there are tight rules around food and plant type stuff. (They don't count computer virii :>)

Comment: Also, no problem posting electronic components - other then Lithium Batteries and - to NZ if you want to go that way.  Provided they cost less then about NZ$400, there are no or taxes, and, because we are an island in the middle of nowhere, most hackers/makers buy there stuff online anyway.

Comment: Relatedly - err on bringing more rather then less bits.  Electronics components are outrageously expensive here (think 5-10 times what they should cost).  If you don't believe me, look at jaycar.co.nz and Surplustronics - the 2 main sources of electronic bits.

Answer (score 3):

I had no problem at all carrying a similar setup for Raspberry Pi a few months ago on Emirates as hand baggage into NZ, including wires, "hat boards", motors and sensors. I did not carry any batteries - I would suggest you buy those locally if you can avoid taking them.

I did get asked at Heathrow and at Bangkok what it all was, but that barely held me up for 30 seconds.